# Where can I find examples of software development and testing documentation?

Tags: test-design, documentation, development-process

I am looking for real-life working examples of documentation of a software development project (including testing). According to some standard, there are a couple of documents involved in software development (not-exhaustive list, might be different from case to case):

- projectplan
- requirements-specification
- systemspecification
- detailspecification
- ...

and especially for testing

- test plan
- test concept
- test design specification
- test case specification
- test reporting
- test procedure specification
- ...

In total there are about 10 different documents involved, for which I can look up templates or a description for each of them, but not really telling me why those are used and what they exactly contain. To me it seems most of the documents are kind of useless and describe the same thing over and over again.

Therefore I am looking for a set of (about 10) example documents which do not contain a template or something, but a *real* documentation of a trivial small software project (e.g. some simple calculation). I want to see that is written in the `requirements documentation`, in the `detail specification`, in the `test concept`, in the `test design document`, in the `test case document`, in the `test detail design execution blah blah documentation` for this given mini project. I hope you get the point.

I will accept a reply as answer, when all of the following conditions are met:

- It contains a link to a page on which I can find most of the above mentioned documents (or as archive).
- All documents refer to the same project
- Every document contains real content, and is *not* a template or something
- Each document is easy to understand

Comment: While you wait for someone to write an answer worthy of your acceptance, you might ponder what kind of committees write standards documents on software development processes, under what circumstances someone would choose to adhere to follow those standards to the letter, and finally whether writing those documents is a good use of time.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is to broad. As you are wondering why these documents are needed, I wonder why you need real world examples to understand their use-case. Maybe you can ask separate questions per document type and not all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements seems to describe document-heavy proprietary process. Unlikely examples of such process would be posted in the open: usually you pay consultants nice hourly rate to teach you/explain you how their process works. Only salesmen (before you fork the money) are free.

Call me a pessimist but I know that snake oil is much easier to sell if company doesn't disclose its ingredients. And CIO would ask salesman very different questions before signing the check than Test Lead would ask, so process if secret ingredient which guarantee success might be easier to sell (and CIO would be more invested to praise how well it works rather than admit his own incompetence by buying something which does not work).

Open-source projects would have much lighter process (definition of agile: communication over the documentation). A big projects may use half of the documents you mentioned. Smaller, more focused and more agile project will use just few.

You may have more luck with open-source ERP systems, google for examples in your favorite programming language.

I am looking forward someone prove me wrong, but my gut feeling is: unlikely, and if, it will come from open-source ERP arena.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't meet all of your requirements, but the SQLite database has a [fairly comprehensive, though high-level, document on its testing](https://sqlite.org/testing.html).

Not sure if you would call this a "test plan" or "test concept"; almost more of a test philosophy or high level documentation of their requirements for development as it relates to testing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no company is going to publish their requirements and testing-plans. Modern open projects are not so documentation heavy, do not expect to find one publicly documented.

What you could try is to retrieve such documentation from a government. More and more governments have a policy that you can request publications of all kinds of stuff. I would guess that it should be possible to request all documents of a software projects your government has been implementing recently. This are also often the projects that are high on formal documentation.